# How do I use rules of inference and implication to solve these two disjunctions?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

[problem http://puu.sh/7RZmi.png](http://puu.sh/7RZmi.png)

How do I get from 4 to ~J v ~R?

Comment: Who says you do? Please explain the notation.

Comment: @Henning, I believe $\supset$ is being used to denote $\rightarrow$, and ~ to represent $\lnot$.

Comment: @amWhy: Sorry, I was unclear -- I can decipher the propositional formulas themselves, but it's not clear to me what it means to arrange them in this particular table in different colors. What does the slash in the left column indicate, for example? Why is $\neg J \lor \neg R$ indented?

Comment: @Henning I concluded the slash represents "that which is to be proved". And I suspect this is from an on-line or software program where the assumptions and goal are in blue, and the OP's work is in black(?)

Comment: Which rules of inference can you use?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have derived step 3 form step 1 using the equivalence between :

> $R \supset V$ and $\lnot R \lor V$.

If we are allowed to do this, I suggest you this derivation :

a) contrapose 1), i.e. from $R \supset V$, derive $\lnot V \supset \lnot R$

then use propositional *syllogism* :

b) from 2) : $J \supset \lnot V$ and a) : $\lnot V \supset \lnot R$, derive : $J \supset \lnot R$.

Finally, apply the equivalence above to get :

> > c) $\lnot J \lor \lnot R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go back to the start:

Try assuming $R \land J$

$(3) R \land J.\;$ ASSUMPTION

Then by simplification, we have

$(4) R$
$(5) J$

From $(1)$, $R\rightarrow V$, so with $(4)$, using  modus ponens, we have

$(6) V.$

From $(2)$, $J\rightarrow \lnot V,$ so with $(5)$ we have

$(7) \lnot V$.

You then derive a contradiction by "anding" (6) and (7):

$(8) V \land \lnot V\;$ ($\land$-Intro)

Because the assumption (3) leads to a contradiction (8), you can negate your assumption:

$(9) \lnot (R \land J)$

$(10)\lnot R \lor \lnot J$, by DeMorgan's on $(9)$.